# Parse an ajax response in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsing

This is the script i wrote to get an ajax response.

```
  <script>
      $( document ).ready(function()
      {
         $("#log").click(function(){
         alert('hellow');
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://1xx.1xx.0.1xx:8081/script.login",
             type: "GET",
             data: { 'page':'create_user', 'access':'user','username':'user', 'password':'user'},
             dataType: "html"
        }).done(function(resp) {

            console.log(resp);

              var $response = $(resp);

        });
        });

      })
  </script>
```

This is how the ajax response body looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" >
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900" >
        <title>Toronto Raptors</title>
        <link href="Html/Panel/ControlPanelStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">




        <!--THIS WILL SUPPRESS ALL ERROR POPUPS-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            var debugMode = false;  //turns on error messages for windows and grids ->false = production build

            //Hide all window errors
            if(debugMode == true){
                function silentErrorHandler() {return true;}
                window.onerror=silentErrorHandler;
            }
        //-->
        </script>


        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: #244A77; 

        }
        a img {
            text-decoration: none;
            border: 0 none;
        }

        Html, body {
            Overflow:hidden;
        }
        font.text {
            visibility:visible;
        }



   #pageContainer{
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background: 244A77; /* for non-css3 browsers */
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#244A77', endColorstr='#7DA7D9'); /* for IE */
         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(244A77), to(7DA7D9)); /* for webkit browsers */
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #244A77, #7DA7D9); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
    }

              /*CSS for resizing counter Widgets*/
        div#counter2containercontainer {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0px auto; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; text-align: center; } 
        div.counter2container {position: relative;  overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto; border: none; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; z-index: 4; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        div#counter5containercontainer {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0px auto; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; text-align: center; } 
        div.counter5container {position: relative;  overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto; border: none; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; z-index: 4; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        div#counter10containercontainer {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0px auto; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; text-align: center; } 
        div.counter10container {position: relative; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto; border: none; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; z-index: 4; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        div#counter11containercontainer {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0px auto; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; text-align: center; } 
        div.counter11container {position: relative; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto; border: none; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; z-index: 4; width: 100%; height: 100%;}


        </style >


           <!--  general window handling -->   
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/dhtmlxwindows.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/skins/dhtmlxwindows_dhx_skyblue.css" />
            <script  type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/dhtmlxwindows.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/dhtmlxcontainer.js"></script>

            <!--Tree - Used for Triggers -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxTree/codebase/dhtmlxtree.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxTree/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxTree/codebase/dhtmlxtree.js"></script>


            <!--acordian Used for Triggers and Healtcare -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxAccordion/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxAccordion/codebase/dhtmlxaccordion.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxAccordion/codebase/skins/dhtmlxaccordion_dhx_skyblue.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxAccordion/codebase/dhtmlxcontainer.js"></script>


            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxMenu/codebase/skins/dhtmlxmenu_dhx_skyblue.css" />
            <script src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxMenu/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
            <script src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxMenu/codebase/dhtmlxmenu.js"></script>



            <!--Other Header Files Required-->


    <!--JAVASCRIPT to autore-size counter widgets-->
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //$(document).ready(function() {

        function divresize(counterName) {
            //alert("RIZSE1");
            var containerName = '.' + counterName + 'container'
            var secondContainer = '#' + counterName + "containercontainer";

            var contentwidth = $(secondContainer ).width();
            var contentheight = $(secondContainer ).height();       
                $(containerName).css('width',contentwidth )
                $(containerName).css('height',contentheight );

                //Better ReSize Attempt...

                //Determine Character Width
                /*var elem = document.getElementById(counterName +"_Value");
                var currentText = elem.innerHTML; 
                var widthMultiplier = 1;
                if(currentText.length > 1){
                    widthMultiplier = (currentText.length);
                    contentwidth = contentwidth / (widthMultiplier);
                }*/


                //Make the size the same as the smaller of the two dimensions

                if(contentwidth <  contentheight){  $('#' + counterName+ '_Value.text').css('font-size',contentwidth / (1.3)); }
                else{ $('#' + counterName+ '_Value.text').css('font-size',contentheight / (1.3));   } 
                //alert("RIZSE");



        }
    </script>



        <!-- dhtmlxGrid -->
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgridcell.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/ext/dhtmlxgrid_ssc.js"></script> 
        <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/dhtmlxgrid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/skins/dhtmlxgrid_dhx_skyblue.css">

        <!--dhtmlxCharts Required-->
        <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxChart/codebase/dhtmlxchart.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxChart/codebase/dhtmlxchart.js"></script>
        <!--Javascript For Speedo and/or Counter Required-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WidgetFiles/jquery.speedometer-1.0.4/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WidgetFiles/jquery.speedometer-1.0.4/jquery.speedometer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WidgetFiles/jquery.speedometer-1.0.4/jquery.jqcanvas-modified.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="WidgetFiles/jquery.speedometer-1.0.4/excanvas-modified.js"></script>




    </head>

<!--<body onload="doOnLoad();" style="background-image: url('../../dhtmxSuite/images/BannerTileBackground.gif'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-color: #87AEC5;" >-->
    <body onload="doOnLoad();"  >





    <div id="pageContainer">



     <div id="counter2_div">
     <div id="counter2containercontainer">
     <div class="counter2container"><font class="text" id="counter2_Value"></font></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div id="counter5_div">
     <div id="counter5containercontainer">
     <div class="counter5container"><font class="text" id="counter5_Value"></font></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div id="counter10_div">
     <div id="counter10containercontainer">
     <div class="counter10container"><font class="text" id="counter10_Value"></font></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div id="counter11_div">
     <div id="counter11containercontainer">
     <div class="counter11container"><font class="text" id="counter11_Value"></font></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div id="pie_medium6_div" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute"></div>
        <div id="speedometer4_div" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;left:0px;top:0px">0</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">$(function(){ $('#speedometer4_div').speedometer();  }); </script>




<!--<div id="winVP" style="position: relative; height: 100%; margin: 0px;"></div>-->


        <div id="triggersActive" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        <div id="triggersHistory" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        <div id="triggerBox" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>

        <div id="pageFooter">Powered By Raptors</div>
    </div>

</body>



<script type="text/javascript">

    var dhxWins;
    var dhxAccord;
    var menu;

    var w999;

    var triggers;
    var showWidgets;
    var tree;

    //Globals needed for banner messages    
    var marqueeQueue = [""];
    var lastMessage = "";
    var lastTrigger = "";
    var lastFiringTriggerList = "";
    var marqueeCounter = 0; 
    var marqueeIndex = 0;

    //Globals needed for initial start positions if null
    var curTopPos = 27;
    var curLeftPos = 0;
    var curBottomPos = 0;
    var windowDim = getBrowserDimensions();
    var maxWidth = windowDim.split(',')[0];
    var maxHeight = windowDim.split(',')[1];
    var initialLoadMode = true;







     var warningBorderSytle = "solid 5px #FFFF00";
     var urgentBorderSytle = "solid 7px #FFA500";
     var criticalBorderSytle = "solid 10px #FF0000";




    function doOnLoad() {


        //Ignore chart Errors       
        if(debugMode ==  false){
            dhtmlxError.catchError("LoadXML",function(a,b,data){ });    
        }


        //Create a viewport and attach to existing div
        dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();



        //dhxWins.enableAutoViewport(false);
        //dhxWins.attachViewportTo("winVP");


         //Handle moving and resizing widgets... save to cookie
         dhxWins.attachEvent("onMoveFinish", function(win){ setWindowStatusCookie(win,1); });
         dhxWins.attachEvent("onResizeFinish", function(win){ setWindowStatusCookie(win,1); });
         dhxWins.attachEvent("onFocus", function(win){ updateZIndex(win); });


         //dhxWins.attachEvent("onClose", function(win){ setWindowStatusCookie(win,0); });


        dhxWins.setImagePath("dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/imgs/");



                dhxWins.attachEvent("onClose", function(win){ win.hide(); });             

                 //ShowWidgets Window
                 showWidgets = dhxWins.createWindow("showWidgets", 0, 30, 250, 600);
                 showWidgets.setText("Add Widget");
                 tree = showWidgets.attachTree();
                 tree.setSkin('dhx_skyblue');
                 tree.setImagePath("../../dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxTree/codebase/imgs/csh_bluefolders/");
                 tree.setOnCheckHandler(widgetTree_oncheck);
                 tree.enableCheckBoxes(true,true);
                 tree.deleteChildItems(0);


     tree.insertNewChild(0, 'w2', "Raptors are back"); 
     tree.insertNewChild(0, 'w5', "Celtics is never the same"); 
     tree.insertNewChild(0, 'w10', "lakers are up"); 
     tree.insertNewChild(0, 'w11', "Heat is going down"); 
     tree.insertNewChild(0, 'w1', "Leafs are back"); 


</script>
```

I am intrested in parsing out the very bottom  part where it says:

tree.insertNewChild(0, 'w2', "Raptors are back");

From this i want to parse out ==> Raptors are back

Can anyone please provide some guidance or clue or help as to how i can do this? I have been stuck on this for 2 days. I am very new to web development in general so i apologize if this is a poorly worded question.

Comment: Is that ajax service out of your control to edit/replace? You should only return what you need from it in a form that is easy to consume (e.g. a JSON string). The idea of Ajax is to reduce bandwidth, not increase it :)

Comment: If you have access to the page this is on (which I assume you do since you're using ajax), why not just remove/change it from there?

Comment: so i should specify dataType as JSON string? The problem is i am not able to do that though. This is why i am stuck with this response body.

Comment: You should only use "json" if you modify that page to return JSON. Right now it's returning an HTML page.

Comment: Yea unfortunately i am not able to change it to return json. it will only return html. that is why i was wondering how to parse this ?=/

Comment: In that case, I would use dataType "string" and write a regex to find the text in question.

Comment: @JakeBraun, That was my first thought but when i change dataType to string it does not return the response body . =/

Comment: "string" isn't a valid dataType, what you want is "text". Even then, it's a cross-origin request, therefore it's going to fail due to the same-origin policy unless the remote server implements cors. If it fails due to same origin and you have no control over the remote server, there's no way to get this data using just javascript.

Comment: @KevinB The dataType text seems to work its giving me a response body. so i can use regex now to find my desired result?

Comment: If you can access the response body, yes.

Comment: @KevinB It seems there is no difference between using dataType html or text both seem to be giving a similar response body. I don't know how good regex would do.

Comment: you should use text, otherwise the responsebody will be parsed as html, including all of the javascript (which could mangle your page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work if you need to accept the result as HTML:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://1xx.1xx.0.1xx:8081/script.login",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'page':'create_user', 'access':'user','username':'user', 'password':'user'},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (html) {
                alert(/tree.insertNewChild\([^"]*"([^"]*?)"\);/g.exec(html)[1]);
            }
    });
```

Here is an example on jFiddle too:
http://jsfiddle.net/hcrM8/16/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
That is the error i got in console of chrome. It seems like that does not quite work =

Comment: Sounds like the regex isn't finding any matches. Trying doing console.log(html) or alert(html) before the above alert line and make sure the html string looks correct at that point.

Comment: Yea i did a console log and it prints out a similar response body as i have mentioned in my Original post. So it seems like it might no be matching correctly.=/

Comment: You might want to try running pieces of the text directly on this line of code: /tree.insertNewChild\([^"]*"([^"]*?)"\);/g.exec("test string here"). If it doesn't work you might need to tweak the regex.

Comment: Got it figured out i decided to use java-script string match :D